# Can I invoke a method 'implicitly' on multiple implementations of the same interface?

Tags: c#, .net, methods

I have the following interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
   void Method1(string someArg);
   void Method2(int anotherArg);
}
```

I have some arbitrary amount of implementations of this interface, I want to loop through them all and invoke method[x] with a given argument.

I could do this with a loop, such as:

```
foreach (var myImplementation in myImplementations)
{
   myImplementation.Method1("ok");
}
```

But, assuming this were in a private method, how can I pass the `Method1("ok");` part as an argument itself?

```
private void InvokeSomething(/*which arg here?*/)
{
    foreach (var myImplementation in myImplementations)
    {
       myImplementation /* how can I make this part implicit? */
    }
}
```

Please assume there are many methods, and there are many implementations (i.e. I want to avoid a `switch` or an `if` here)

Comment: `InvokeSomethingOnInterface(Action<MyInterface> action) => action()`, what have you tried?

Comment: If you search "C# pass interface method as parameter", which appears to be your actual question, you'll find plenty of hits. My point was: have you tried anything like _that_? I'm not asking that for the sake of asking that, I'm asking it to find out whether you have found anything and it didn't work.

Comment: Half of the battle of knowing how to search for something is knowing how to word your search, I wasn't aware it would be the method that was being passed as a parameter. You've assumed I've known more about the solution than I did.

Comment: It's literally in your question: "how can I pass the [method call] part as an argument", and if you search the web for that, you'll find plenty of hits. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a *lamda expression* as an argument:

```
private void InvokeSomething(Action<MyInterface> action)
{
    foreach (var myImplementation in myImplementations)
    {
         action.Invoke(myImplementation);
         // or: action(myImpelementation) - the ".Invoke" is optional.
    }
}
```

which can be called as follows:

```
InvokeSomething(i => i.Method1("ok"));
```

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was after, thank you.